# Configuring Nginx for Phalcon on a Plesk 11.5 server

Tags: php, nginx, plesk, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I've been working on a project with Phalcon in local development environment (Vagrant + Virtualbox). It just works great and my development time really decreased.

Now I would like to put this project online in a Plesk 11.5 nginx environment and I run into the problem of configuring Nginx in Plesk for Phalcon. I'm also quite new to Nginx.

I have the following Nginx configuration:

```
server {

    listen   80;
    server_name localhost.dev;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    set $root_path '/var/www/httpdocs';
    root $root_path;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I removed the "server {}" because those are not allowed in Plesk nginx configuration. However, it just doesn't work. The homepage of the application is shown perfectly, so Phalcon is running just fine, but the routing doesn't work: /search just gives a 404 where it does work in my local envoronment with this configuration.

What should I change in Plesk to make this work?

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all check is PHP on your domain processing by PHP-FPM, or by Apache.

In case you using nginx just like reverse proxy for apache and PHP processed by apache you just need to place Phalcon bootstrap index.php and .htaccess into /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs and all other application files to /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld
(I've successfully run Phalcon tutorial on such configuration)

In case of PHP-FPM the most easiest way is to define [custom virtual host template](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-linux-advanced-administration-guide/index.htm?fileName=68693.htm)

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain
cp /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/
```

And in /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php make condition for your domain name just echo whole complete config like:

```
<?php if $VAR->domain->asciiName == 'your-domain.tld' ?>

    plain text of your full nginx config here

<?php   else: ?>

   plesk default instruction for all other domains

<?php endif ?>
```